# error installing eclipse neon 2 bluemix plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-plugin

I am trying to install the Bluemix plugin on Eclipse Neon.2 but it constantly throws an error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: WebSphere® Application Server Liberty Tools 1.0.2.v20161130_1957 (com.ibm.cftools.server.tools.feature.feature.group 1.0.2.v20161130_1957)
  Missing requirement: WebSphere® Application Server Liberty Tools 16.0.4000.v20161213_2112 (com.ibm.websphere.wdt.server.tools.feature.group 16.0.4000.v20161213_2112) requires 'com.ibm.ws.ast.ws.tools.feature.group 1.0.100' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WebSphere® Application Server Liberty Tools 1.0.2.v20161130_1957 (com.ibm.cftools.server.tools.feature.feature.group 1.0.2.v20161130_1957)
    To: com.ibm.websphere.wdt.server.tools.feature.group 8.5.5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried by downloading the latest Eclipse JEE Neon.2 package, e.g. from http://eclipse.bluemix.net/packages/neon.2/.  Then, I got to Eclipse Marketplace from Eclipse IDE and find Bluemix Tools from the Eclipse marketplace to do the install the Bluemix Tools using the default installation options.  I can install the Bluemix Tools successfully. I do not see the error that you described.

Can you describe the exact steps that you use for doing the install?